# Mongo populate not working and not retrieve data model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem in populate method in mongodb it can't retrieve data from model. Can anyone help me solve that problem?

This is the code

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = req.user._id;
    const wishlist = await Wishlist.find({ user, isLiked: true })
      .populate({
        path: 'Products',
        select: 'title',
      })
      .sort('-updated');

    res.status(200).json({
      wishlist,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: 'Your request could not be processed. Please try again.',
    });
  }
});
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/wishlist/`, this is the response I get:

```
{
    "wishlist": [
        {
            "product": "60cb5eb82cc7091ae2e31c88",
            "user": "60cb6c46291247466fe08f92",
            "isLiked": true,
            "_id": "60d1a656567e08bf89571209",
            "updated": "2021-06-22T10:09:25.295Z",
            "created": "2021-06-22T08:59:02.434Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

The model of products

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Categories',
    default: null
  },
  photo: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
  },
  updateAt: Date,
  price: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number
  }
  ,
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

The model for wishlist:

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = Mongoose;

// Wishlist Schema
const WishlistSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Product',
    default: null,
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    default: null,
  },
  isLiked: {
    type: Boolean,
     
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Mongoose.model('Wishlist', WishlistSchema);
```

Can anyone help me please to find the solution for that problem?

Comment: `populate({path: 'product',...})` not `Products`